# Using DoCheck in attribute directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I've created a simple app using `ngFor` to create a series of buttons from an array. When a button is clicked, it's value is pushed to a second array.

I have an attribute directive `disable` that listens for changes to the array using `DoCheck()` and disables any button whose value already exists in the array to prevent it from being added more than once.

It all works but is there a better approach? The Angular 2 site advises caution when using `DoCheck()`.

**View**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let myitem of myitems">{{ myitem }}
    <a href="#" (click)="deleteItem(myitem)"> x</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<button *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="addItem(item)" [disable]="myitems">{{item}}</button>
```

**Attribute Directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[disable]'
})
export class DisableDirective implements DoCheck {
  @Input('disable') myitems : string[];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { }

  ngDoCheck() {
      if(this.myitems.find(item => item === this.el.nativeElement.innerText)) {
        this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', true);
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', true);
      } else {
        this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', false);
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', false);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the `[disabled]` property of the `button`. Create a function in your controller `isButtonDisabled(button)` where you pass the item from the template.

```
<button 
  *ngFor="let item of items" 
  (click)="addItem(item)"
  [disable]="myitems" 
  [disabled]="isButtonDisabled(item)"
> 
 {{item}} 
</button>
```

Inside the function, check if the item is already pushed into the second array.

If yes, `return true` so the button gets disabled.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using a `directive` why not perform the check in `addItem()` method in your component.

`DoCheck()` method should have limited use as  it's going to **run every time a change detection cycle run**. so you have to be careful in using it.

It's preferred to use `OnChanges()` instead of `DoCheck()` as the former runs only when there's change in `input` properties.

you can try :

```
 export class MyComponent implents OnChanges{

    addItem(item) {

    if(this.myitems.find(item => item === this.el.nativeElement.innerText)) {
            this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', true);
            this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', true);
          } 
else {
            this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', false);
            this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', false);
          }
      }
    }

ngOnChanges() {
this.addItem(item);
}
```

in your case you can skip using `directive`.

if really want to use `directive`, then shift all the logic from `DoCheck()` to `OnChanges()` .